# jQuery - Ajax - How do I load an ascx into the DIV, when the user changes the selected index in the DropDownList

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, custom-server-controls

In A.ascx I have one DropDownList and one DIV. The DropDownList is populated dynamically.

How do I load B.ascx into the DIV, when the user changes the selected index in the DropDownList. This should be done on the client side without postback, by using jQuery and Ajax.

Comment: are you loading different user controls into the div depending on the selection or is the content of the second user control just dynamic based on the selected item?

Answer (score -1):

```
  function selectedindexchange() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "CONTROLNAME.ascx",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      $('#ContentDIV').html(msg.d);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: I don't think you can use *.ascx  as urls for ajax post. Only page name is valid.